# Compare and filter from 2 files

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to compare and filter the differences from two dat files. To be more specific 2 files with around 2000 lines of code each. Both files have a lot in common so I am trying to filter the different parts. I made the first part which compares the two files, but I need to filter them up, since the comparing is line by line. For example file1.dat has include in line 100 and the file2.dat has the same `include in line 102. So line by line comparison is not helping me with the filtering.

Here is my script:

```
import re

filename = "{0}_{1}.txt"
name = filename.format(f'{"TB"}', f'{"Differences"}')

# reading files
f = open(name,'w')
f1 = open("file1.dat", "r")
f2 = open("file2.dat", "r")  
i = 0
#######COLORS#######
 CRED = '\033[91m'
 CGREEN = '\33[32m'
 CEND = '\033[0m'
####################

 for line1 in f1:
   i += 1
   line1 = re.sub(" +", " ", line1)
  
    for line2 in f2:
      line2 = re.sub(" +", " ", line2)
    # matching line1 from both files
    if line1 == line2:  
        print(" Line ", i, ": PASS") 
        f.write("PASS\n")             
            
    else:
        print(CGREEN + " Line ", i, ":" + CEND)
        # else print that line from both files
        print(CRED + "\tFAIL" + CEND)
        print("\tFile 1:", line1, end='')
        print("\tFile 2:", line2, end='')
        f.write(f"Difference found in Line {i}\n ")
        f.write(f"Line {i} in {f1}--> {line1} ")
        f.write(f"Line {i} in {f2}--> {line2}")
        
    break
  
    # closing files
    f1.close()                                       
    f2.close() 
    f.close()
```

Sample:
Input file1.dat has:

```
 [1] import execnet
 [2]
 [3] def call_python_version(Version, Module, Function, ArgumentList):
 [4] gw      = execnet.makegateway("popen//python=python%s" % Version)
 [5] channel = gw.remote_exec("""
 [6]  from %s import %s as the_function
 [7]  channel.send(the_function(*channel.receive()))
 [8] """ % (Module, Function))
 [9] channel.send(ArgumentList)
 [10] return channel.receive()
```

Input file2.dat has:

```
 [1] import execnet
 [2]
 [3] def call_python_version(Version, Module, Function, ArgumentList):
 [4] gw      = execnet.makegateway("popen//python=python%s" % Version)
 [5] % (Module, Function))
 [6] from %s import %s as the_function
 [7] channel2.send(the_function(*channel2.receive()))
 [8] channel2 = gw.remote_exec("""
 [9] channel2.send(ArgumentList)
 [10] return channel2.receive()
```

Output txt has:

```
 file1 = channel = gw.remote_exec("""
 file2 = channel2 = gw.remote_exec("""
 file1 = channel.send(the_function(*channel.receive()))
 file2 = channel2.send(the_function(*channel2.receive()))
 .
 .
 .
```

Comment: what is your desire output?

Comment: A txt file that has in it the differences as line of code from the two dat files.

Comment: if possible then add sample input and output file

Comment: @Sabil Done, hope you understand the idea

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to ask yourself; are you comparing code, or are you comparing lines? If comparing code, it becomes tricky in the sense that you need to take into account whitespace, allow for reverse function order, differences in indentation, etc. If you are comparing code, you are probably better off using Python's [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) module to compare parts.

If you are strictly comparing lines, then save yourself a lot of work and use an external library such as [deepdiff](https://pypi.org/project/deepdiff/) (no association). I suspect it will give you most of what you need right out of the box.

Here is an example of using deepdiff (works as is);

**pip install deepdiff**

```
from pprint import pprint
from textwrap import dedent
from deepdiff import DeepDiff

file1 = dedent('''
 [1] import execnet
 [2]
 [3] def call_python_version(Version, Module, Function, ArgumentList):
 [4] gw      = execnet.makegateway("popen//python=python%s" % Version)
 [5] channel = gw.remote_exec("""
 [6]  from %s import %s as the_function
 [7]  channel.send(the_function(*channel.receive()))
 [8] """ % (Module, Function))
 [9] channel.send(ArgumentList)
 [10] return channel.receive()
''').split("\n")

file2 = dedent('''
 [1] import execnet
 [2]
 [3] def call_python_version(Version, Module, Function, ArgumentList):
 [4] gw      = execnet.makegateway("popen//python=python%s" % Version)
 [5] % (Module, Function))
 [6] from %s import %s as the_function
 [7] channel2.send(the_function(*channel2.receive()))
 [8] channel2 = gw.remote_exec("""
 [9] channel2.send(ArgumentList)
 [10] return channel2.receive()
''').split("\n")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    diff = DeepDiff(file1, file2)
    pprint(diff)
```

**Output**

```
{'values_changed': {'root[10]': {'new_value': '[10] return channel2.receive()',
                                 'old_value': '[10] return channel.receive()'},
                    'root[5]': {'new_value': '[5] % (Module, Function))',
                                'old_value': '[5] channel = '
                                             'gw.remote_exec("""'},
                    'root[6]': {'new_value': '[6] from %s import %s as '
                                             'the_function',
                                'old_value': '[6]  from %s import %s as '
                                             'the_function'},
                    'root[7]': {'new_value': '[7] '
                                             'channel2.send(the_function(*channel2.receive()))',
                                'old_value': '[7]  '
                                             'channel.send(the_function(*channel.receive()))'},
                    'root[8]': {'new_value': '[8] channel2 = '
                                             'gw.remote_exec("""',
                                'old_value': '[8] """ % (Module, Function))'},
                    'root[9]': {'new_value': '[9] channel2.send(ArgumentList)',
                                'old_value': '[9] channel.send(ArgumentList)'}}}
```